# SQL select distinct max issue

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, max

I'm trying to combine distinct and max on this table

```
id      name      surname   group   year
113865  JOHN      RED       29      2012
112756  ANNE      REDS      128     2011
111960  MATT      RED       88      2011
108615  JOHN      RED       29      2011
102801  JOHN      REDMOND   29      2010
98152   CARL      RED       36      2009
98175   MANUEL    RED       36      2009
96569   JOHN      RED       31      2009
95684   CARL      RED       36      2008
95685   MANUEL    RED       36      2008
```

I would like to filter for distinct name, surname in the same group with highest year

```
id      name      surname   group   year
113865  JOHN      RED       29      2012
112756  ANNE      REDS      128     2011
111960  MATT      RED       88      2011
102801  JOHN      REDMOND   29      2010
98152   CARL      RED       36      2009
98175   MANUEL    RED       36      2009
96569   JOHN      RED       31      2009
```

what's the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `group by` rather than `distinct`:

```
select name, surname, group, max(year)
from TheTable
group by name, surname, group
```

Result:

```
name      surname   group   year
JOHN      RED       29      2012
ANNE      REDS      128     2011
MATT      RED       88      2011
JOHN      REDMOND   29      2010
CARL      RED       36      2009
MANUEL    RED       36      2009
JOHN      RED       31      2009
```

I didn't include the `id` field, as you haven't specified which value you want for each distinct row. If you for example want the highest id, you can use `max(id)` to include it in the result.

You *can* include the `id` field in list and MySQL will include it in the result, but the result for that field isn't predictable. Some other databases, like MS SQL Server, won't allow you to include it in the result without using an aggregate like for example `max`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.id, t2.name, t2.surname, t2.year, t2.group
from
(select group, name, surname, MAX(Year) as year
from table
group by group, name, surname) t2 
INNER JOIN table t1 ON t1.name = t2.name 
and t1.surname = t2.surname 
and t1.year = t2.year
and t1.group = t2.group
```